# Multi-site login bar

Tags: php

How does one implement a multi-site login bar?  I am starting a personal project that would require a header bar above multiple sites that allows users to login or do other things, I am coding this in PHP and have not been able to find anything online other than wordpress plugins.

EDIT: Sorry I wrote this late last night so I was very vague about it. I'll go into a bit more detail.

An example would be the StackExchange bar at the top, I will have one unified login database that each site will access.

I guess I just am curious how best to implement this via PHP or some MVC framework.

Comment: Are the sites connected somehow, such as sharing databases?

Comment: Have you looked at the related articles? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180215/multi-site-login-ala-google?rq=1), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387879/php-multi-site-login?rq=1)

Comment: You are referring to [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). Could you share an example of a "Multi-site login bar" or describe what it would look like.

Comment: Are you planning to build your own custom SSO implementation or would you be using a 3rd provider such as Facebook, Google...?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add along with a `username` and `password` fields, a `site` field, probably a `select` input element.

Before you process the login credentials you would see what site the user has selected and take it from there.

I'm assuming you are coding this yourself for a custom project.

If you know `sql` and basic `php` `sessions` or `cookies` then this shouldn't be too difficult.